# Moving Oracle Schemas to newer version

Tags: oracle11g, oracle9i

I have few db schemas in `Oracle 9.2.0.8` and i have to move these schemas into `Oracle 11.2.0.1.0`. What is the best way of doing this?

I found a way that these schemas can be exported in 9i using `exp` utility and import these scheams into Oracle 11gR2 DB using `imp`. Any thoughts will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Are you really moving individual schemas from one database to another?  Or are you really trying to upgrade the 9.2.0.8 database to 11.2.0.1?

Answer (score 0):

If the schemas have to be moved, using exp/imp is the recommended way. However this only works if the schemas are self-contained. If they are not self-contained than the referred to schemas also need to be exported and imported. In addition do not forget to analyze the objects after the import and take a backup.